# Stripe and React, react-stripe-element custom card element without zip field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am newbie in stripe and react.

I am trying to create a stripe checkout screen which has already been designed. 
[image]

Now when I add `CardElement` component it create a new row which looks like this
[image]

I would like it use my own custom styled elements, is there any way to pass these as props style them custom

Regards

Comment: have you got the solution please let me know i'm also stuck on the same

Answer (score 2):

On the topic of styling Stripe Card Elements. I would recommend checking out the following parts of the Stripe.js docs:

1. https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/the_element_container
2. https://stripe.com/docs/js/appendix/style
3. https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_element?type=card

Ultimately, there are both `classes` and `style` parameters that you can work with to change the style of your Card Element.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CardElement, You can use all separate elements like this :

```
 <CardNumberElement />
 <CardExpiryElement />
 <CardCvcElement/>

const paymentMethod = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
        type: "card",
        card: cardNumber,
      });
```

and pass CardNumber in place of CardElement in your function. So, you can easily style your payment card.

Now, you can give separate CSS to each of your element by wrapping it around div.